# How to get the data of an api id in a page with vue router?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vuex, vue-router

I'm performing a search in the API, I bring the results to "/results", but each result is to have a detail, that is, for example: When clicking on the detail button, it is to pull the :id_produção, and the URL is something as /results/detail/:production

How to redirect to a new page, bringing only the data of a certain /:production  ???

[image: router archive]

[image: button detail]

> API SEARCH RESULT BELOW

```json
[
  {
    "id_producao": 2,
    "titulo": "Chico da Pesca",
    "ano": 2019,
    "resumo": "dajdhada",
    "orientador": "Chico",
    "usuario": {
      "id_usuario": 7,
      "nome": "teste",
      "email": "teste@gmail.com",
      "linkLattes": null,
      "nomeImagem": null
    },
    "areaConhecimento": {
      "id_area_conhecimento": 5,
      "nomeArea": "Computação"
    },
    "instituicao": {
      "id_instituicao": 2,
      "nomeInstituicao": "Universidade Ceuma",
      "endereco": "Renascença"
    }
  },
  {
    "id_producao": 3,
    "titulo": "Isso é uma falácia!",
    "ano": 2010,
    "resumo": "Uma rede de computadores é importante",
    "orientador": "Marcos Sá",
    "usuario": 7,
    "areaConhecimento": {
      "id_area_conhecimento": 5,
      "nomeArea": "Computação"
    },
    "instituicao": {
      "id_instituicao": 1,
      "nomeInstituicao": "Pitaguras",
      "endereco": "Turu"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think state management like [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) or [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/) may resolve your problem. Store product list in `data`, when you navigate to detail page, using `getters` to get product detail by `product id`